# Why can not I install the newest software like windows?

Tags: updates

I know there are many dependences.

Why not keep dependences and software in a pack like in windows ?
I mean let software afford its newer dependence with itself.

Thanks

Comment: What software is this about? The default APT repos are kept frozen to prevent dependencies breaking, you can usually install the latest from a PPA. Windows can do this because it doesn't have a central package management program like APT, each program is distributed seperately

Comment: Possible dup based on the title alone: http://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have installed a deb package and it might have shown you that some dependencies are not met. I think you should open a terminal after you installed the package and run the below command to fulfil it.

`$ sudo apt-get install -f`

This should fulfil the dependencies.

BTW, because of that non-sense technology, Windows OS and basic programs take 30+ Gig space while Ubuntu takes hardly 8 Gig for the same.

Comment: He didn't say anything about having broken packages or unmet dependencies.

Comment: @psusi I know but I felt that is his problem; otherwise apt will take care of all the dependencies and one need not think of this unless a .deb package is installed directly. I suggested as per my understanding and let him see if it addresses his problem...

Comment: He doesn't *have* a problem.  He is asking a general question about packaging software.

Comment: I too hope for the same...